# Python related error, not able to find the path

Tags: python

I am running a code containing the following piece at the beginning -

```
#Set path(command) to Sai
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
path_to_Sai = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
else:
print("Error")
print("Usage: python do_all.py path_to_Sai.")
print("path_to_Sai: relative or absolute path to Sai.")
exit(1)
```

When I run the code it prints the error contained in the print commands.

Could you please help me in sorting it out?

Answer (score 2):

From the code you provide I can imagine that you are forgetting that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, so if you providing 2 arguments, `len(sys.argv)` is equal to 3, not 2.

You should add at least the following code:

```
print(len(sys.argv))
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    print(sys.argv[i])
```

this should help you to figure out what is happening.

Comment: But the help message only suggests one argument. It seems more likely that they are forgetting to provide a file name.

Comment: @tripleee but those are not error messages that he is getting back, those are strings that are printed...

Comment: Yes. Precisely. Why do you imagine they are passing two file names when the usage message suggests that they should provide one? More likely they are not reading the message and providing none.

Comment: Ok, I get your point! This may be what is happening!

Comment: @fabianod, what is the conclusion? What should i do ?

Comment: @explorer I edited the answer with a piece of code that helps you to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If adding another dependency isn't prohibitive, I'd suggest using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    prog='ProgramName',
                    description='What the program does',
                    epilog='Text at the bottom of help')
parser.add_argument('filepath')

arguments = parser.parse_args()

path_to_HPhi = arguments.filepath
```

This way you can specify a plethora of arguments with relative ease, define defaults, keyword-arguments, ...

Also, it automatically creates a help/error message if required arguments are missing or unexpected arguments were provided.

Of course, just going by the code snippet you provided, using argparse might be overkill, but it's hard to tell, without knowing how you invoke the script and if you need other arguments as well. It will definitely make extending your script easier in the future if you might add more parameters.